# error: database driver: unknown driver postgresql (forgotten import?) - How to run golang migrate with make file

Tags: postgresql, go, database-migration, golang-migrate

I am trying to run migrations in my go-fiber rest API using golang-migrate.

I added the commands for running the migrations in a makefile. However, when I run `make migrateup`, I get the following error:

```
migrate -path database/postgres/migrations -database "postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5400/property?sslmode=disable" -verbose up
2022/11/10 18:00:17 error: database driver: unknown driver postgresql (forgotten import?)
make: *** [Makefile:15: migrateup] Error 1
```

This is the make file I am using.

```
#### IMPORT ENV
include .env
DB_URL=postgresql://$(DB_USER):$(DB_PASSWORD)@$(DB_HOST):$(DB_PORT)/$(DB_NAME)?sslmode=disable

postgres:
    docker run --name postgres -p $(DB_PORT):5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=$(DB_USER) -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(DB_PASSWORD) -d postgres:alpine

createdb:
    docker exec -it postgres createdb --username=$(DB_USER) --owner=$(DB_OWNER) $(DB_NAME)

dropdb:
    docker exec -it postgres dropdb --username=$(DB_USER) $(DB_NAME)

migrateup:
    migrate -path database/postgres/migrations -database "$(DB_URL)" -verbose up

migratedown:
    migrate -path database/postgres/migrations -database $(DB_URL) -verbose down

.PHONY: postgres createdb dropdb
```

Please can anyone help me understand why this is not working?

Answer (score 1):

first you install driver database.

database migration `go install -tags "postgres,mysql" github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate@latest`

im use code makefile

```
table = $(table)
name = $(name)
url=postgres://postgres:secret@127.0.0.1:5432/school?sslmode=disable
version=$(version)
migration-up :
    migrate -database "$(url)" -path ./migrations/ up $(version)
    
migration-down :
    migrate -database "$(url)" -path ./migrations/ down $(version)
    
migration-create:
    migrate create -ext sql -dir ./migrations/ -seq $(name)

migration-force:
    migrate -database "$(url)" -path ./migrations/ force $(version)

migration-version:
    migrate -database "$(url)" -path ./migrations/ version
```

`make migration-create name=users` create file migration

`make migration-up version=1` run migration up to running file sql

Answer (score 0):

You need to install golang-migrate with special tag to have support of particular driver.

It's written in documentation of command line tool: https://github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/tree/master/cmd/migrate#with-go-toolchain

Answer (score 0):

This issue was resolved by uninstalling golang migrate and installing it again. After that, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Postgres driver. For it you need to install golang migrate with tags 'postgres'. After this every should works :)
`go install -tags 'postgres' github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/cmd/migrate@latest`